# Unable to group by to equal values in columns when values are from case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a view i created

```
SELECT YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - YEAR(c.date_of_birth) - (RIGHT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 5) < RIGHT(c.date_of_birth, 5)) as age, count(a.id) as occurences, a.celex_id,

COUNT(CASE WHEN c.gender = 'MALE' THEN c.id END) as males,
COUNT(CASE WHEN c.gender = 'FEMALE' THEN c.id END) as females,
COUNT(CASE WHEN c.gender IS NULL THEN c.id END) as unknowns

FROM consumer c, account a

WHERE a.consumer_id = c.id

GROUP BY age, a.celex_id;
```

This results in:

```
age | occurences | celex_id | male | female | unknowns
------------------------------------------------------
16  | 1          | 1        | 0    | 1      | 0
65  | 1          | 1        | 1    | 0      | 0
66  | 1          | 1        | 0    | 1      | 0
69  | 1          | 1        | 0    | 0      | 1
```

And so on.

Now, I have made a query with a case statement, but I am unable to group by the cases, this is the query

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN age BETWEEN 0  AND 10 THEN '0-10'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '51-60'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN '61-70'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN '71-80'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN '81-90'
    WHEN age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN '91-100'
    WHEN age > 100 THEN 'Greater than 100'
ELSE 'Unknown'
END AS age_range, males, females, unknowns
FROM age_gender_occurences
WHERE celex_id = 1
GROUP BY age_range, males, females, unknowns
```

This gives

```
age_range | males | females | unknowns
--------------------------------------
11-20     | 0     | 1       | 0
21-30     | 0     | 1       | 0
61-70     | 0     | 1       | 0
61-70     | 1     | 0       | 0
61-70     | 0     | 0       | 1
```

I have tried replicating the case statement directly in the GROUP BY clause, but this does not work. Can someone shed some light over how i can get the age_range to become one-liners? (like 61-70 becoming 1 line instead of 3)

Comment: Understand how `GROUP BY` works. `GROUP BY x, y, z` means "I want one result row per x/y/z combination". You want one result row per age_range, so you'd `GROUP BY age_range` only accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the aggregation functions.  I would write this in terms of the original tables:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 0  AND 10 THEN '0-10'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '51-60'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN '61-70'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN '71-80'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN '81-90'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN '91-100'
             WHEN age > 100 THEN 'Greater than 100'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
         END) AS age_range,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.gender = 'MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as males,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.gender = 'FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as females,
        SUM(CASE WHEN c.gender IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as unknowns
FROM consumer c JOIN
     account a
     ON a.consumer_id = c.id
WHERE celex_id = 1
GROUP BY age_range;
```

If you want to write it in terms of the view (which seems overkill):

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN age BETWEEN 0  AND 10 THEN '0-10'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN '21-30'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 31 AND 40 THEN '31-40'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 41 AND 50 THEN '41-50'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 51 AND 60 THEN '51-60'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 61 AND 70 THEN '61-70'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 71 AND 80 THEN '71-80'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN '81-90'
             WHEN age BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN '91-100'
             WHEN age > 100 THEN 'Greater than 100'
             ELSE 'Unknown'
         END) AS age_range,
        SUM(males) as males,
        SUM(females) as females,
        SUM(unknowns) as unknowns
FROM age_gender_occurences
WHERE celex_id = 1
GROUP BY age_range;
```

In other words, you need to aggregate *again*.  And, in fact, MySQL will do two aggregations in this case, which is why I recommend the simpler version of just using the original tables.

Comment: There was some errors from your query, but when i worked them out I got the correct results, thank you!

Comment: @Daniel . . . You can either fix the answer or let me know what the errors are.